# php upload, I get error UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE, but file size very small

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I try to load file. It file have size about 65kb. But php-script give me an error.
My server work with docker. What may be problem?

Code:

```
if ($_FILES) {
    var_dump($_FILES); die;
}
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "ava.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(1)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

In phpinfo I get:

```
file_uploads    On
max_file_uploads    20
upload_max_filesize 5М
post_max_size   8M
```

In nginx .conf file

client_max_body_size 128M;

Comment: Did you call phpinfo from within that same script? If not, do a `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');` in there, just to first of all verify that in that script’s context the value actually is what you think it is.

Comment: Show what error you have

Comment: You get this error because your post_max_size is bigger than upload_max_filesize

Comment: @Milad _“because your post_max_size is bigger than upload_max_filesize”_ - 65kb is much smaller than _both_ of them, so that makes little sense. They would have to send _megabytes_ of other form data at the same time to run into post_max_size , and if that was the case, I suppose it would have been mentioned in the problem description.

Comment: @manqlele yes its equal answer, thank you